# How to use Huggingface pretrained models to get the output of the dataset that was used to train the model?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, summarization, huggingface-datasets

I am working on getting the abstractive summaries of the XSUM and the CNN DailyMail datasets using Huggingface's pre-trained BART, Pegasus, and T5 models.

I am confused because there already exist checkpoints of models pre-trained on the same dataset.

So even if I do:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mwesner/pretrained-bart-CNN-Dailymail-summ")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("mwesner/pretrained-bart-CNN-Dailymail-summ")
```

I can't understand how to get the summaries of either dataset since I don't have any new sentences that I can feed in.

This is how a pretrained model is normally used:

```py
from transformers import BartTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration, BartConfig

model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')

ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE = "My friends are cool but they eat too many carbs."

inputs = tokenizer([ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE], max_length=1024, return_tensors='pt')

# Generate Summary
summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'], num_beams=4, max_length=5, early_stopping=True)
print([tokenizer.decode(g, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) for g in summary_ids])
```

But I need the summaries generated by the pre-trained model on the dataset that was used to train them (XSUM and CNN DailyNews).

Comment: You mean you want a summary generated by `mwesner/pretrained-bart-CNN-Dailymail-summ` for each sample of CNN-dailymail?

Comment: Yes I need a summary generated by the pretrained model for each sample of CNN-dailymail and each sample of XSUM... I have taken mwesner/pretrained-bart-CNN-Dailymail-summ as an example but I've looked at many pre-trained checkpoints.

Comment: @cronoik Do you know how I could possibly proceed? Could you please help?

Comment: You can load the cnnmail with `from datasets import load_dataset
` and  `dataset = load_dataset("cnn_dailymail", "3.0.0",  split="test")` and iterate over the article column.